# How is it that both Camilla and Palamedes are in Camilla's body?

Tags: locked-tomb, nona-the-ninth

In the early pages of *Nona the Ninth* (2022, Tamsyn Muir), Camilla Hect and Warden Palamedes are seen to be sharing Camilla's body, with similar change to eye color to what's seen with lyctors in the first and second books of the series -- but in *Gideon the Ninth* we saw that

> the necromancer always provides the body when necromancer and cavalier are joined to create a lyctor -- and Palamedes had died in that book.

We had confirmation in *Harrow the Ninth* that Camilla (then in captivity by Blood of Eden) gave no sign of hosting Palamedes -- in fact, the latter was

> found in a small enclave within the River when Harrowhark dove in near the end of that book.

Did I miss an explanation of how Palamedes was able to rejoin with Camilla in the "wrong" body for a lyctor union near the end of *Harrow*?

I do *not* want spoilers for *Nona* -- I've just started reading it today and will likely be a week or more getting through it due to very limited reading time.

Comment: Do we really need individual tags for all the books mentioned in the question?

Comment: @DavidW Isn't it normal for individual works to have tags?  Author tag is wrong here, as I'm not asking anything about Tamsyn herself, and there wasn't a preexisting tag for any of them or the series (they're pretty new).  Not to mention all three (so far) books enter into this question.

Comment: You're not wrong, but it seems excessive for a single question to introduce a series tag and _three_ individual work tags.  ISTM the question can't actually be specifically about all four of those things, so maybe just [tag:nona-the-ninth], which is what you're really asking about, and optionally the series tag [tag:locked-tomb] if it's possible there will be many questions about various of these works.  Basically I'm just feeling that one question introducing four new tags seems a bit much.

Comment: Okay, I'll agree, the question is *about* *Nona* and carries into knowledge from the rest of the series.  I'll dump the excess tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not directly explained.**

There's hints dropped all over though.  Potential spoilers for anyone who has not read Gideon the Ninth or Harrow the Ninth.

- Palamedes had worked out what a Lyctor union would require and flat out refused to do it.  When Harrow peeks in on his soul in the River bubble, he reacts with horror when Harrow's actions imply that she had gone through with it.
- Both Camilla and Palamedes are from the house most dedicated to research and information.  Having determined how to become a Lyctor, and not doing it, does not mean either would stop thinking on the implications and working out what possibilities might exist.  This is implied to be how he managed to tether his bubble, soul intact, to his remains.
- Harrow reshapes what remains Camilla has into a set of hand bones, which may not seem like much, but given his cleverness, doesn't just give him possible mobility, but more importantly *communication with Camilla*.

Since some spoilers are heavier than others, rest in spoiler block below.

> The multiple situations revealed at the end of Harrow the Ninth - namely, that Gideon the First's cavalier Pyrrha Dve survived with some awareness and resurfacing, that Harrow's "partial" Lyctor allowed her Gideon's soul to survive, that John Gaius himself has some kind of bond that swapped his eyes despite the person he swapped with being alive enough to be locked in the Tomb... - all points to the Lyctors only dabbling at the first steps of working necromancy with souls.

Comment: I'll also note that while the how is not gone into, and the why is obvious, the what happens now is discussed.  Like Harrow, their situation is not without complications.

Comment: So I've just seen -- read the "last time swimming" scene and its aftermath during my breaks yesterday and this morning.

Comment: There was actually one more hint on this that I only picked up recently, but it's in Nona, not the earlier books.  Watch the last scene with Palamedes and Camilla carefully; chances are they just finished a process they'd begun the same way.